# echo flag -n is printing out when run from script

Tags: bash, echo

When I run the following command from the terminal:

```
echo -n hello >> output.txt
```

It appends 'hello' to the file and doesn't add a trailing newline, which is what I want it to do.

However, if I have a file named `prog.sh` with that exact same line as its sole contents, and run it from terminal with

```
sh prog.sh
```

then it appends '-n hello' to the file with a trailing newline.

I have run scripts using this before, and it has never been a problem. What am I missing?

Comment: `sh` is not `bash` (or more precisely, `bash` when invoked as `sh` behaves differently). POSIX doesn't require that `-n` be treated as an option; it only *allows* for it to be an option.

Comment: @chepner `sh prog.sh` works for me - it does write "hello" without new line. What makes the difference?

Comment: That's interesting, however I've used exactly that wording (obviously on more complex scripts) hundreds of times before, and it's never been a problem.
Running it with `bash prog.sh` does work properly, but I can't work out why it has always worked in the past, but doesn't work now. What could have changed?

Comment: @HenryBrice Computers do not obey us anymore. Within few years you'll run bash script for them.

Comment: Henry, try 1) `/bin/sh echo -n hello`, 2) switching `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` in the script and running it again, and 3) doing `which sh` to make sure `sh` and `/bin/sh` are the same program.  The results from those should definitively tell us whether chepner's right about your `sh` not supporting `echo -n`.

Comment: The right thing to do is stop using `echo`, and use `printf` instead: `printf '%s' hello`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun When invoked as `sh`, `bash` 3.2 treats `-n` as a regular argument to print. Starting with `bash` 4, it treats it as an option to supress a newline. All the more reason to stop using `echo` if you expect consistent results.

Comment: @chepner How do you know that `printf` will be interpreted the same? (In general, how can I know if a command I use is the same in all tools?).

Comment: @chepner if you add an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: The POSIX standard simply threw up its hands and allowed `echo`'s behavior to be implementation-defined to accommodate the variety of historical implementations. `printf` was much more consistent to begin with, and so is much more strictly defined.

Comment: @MarounMaroun A good write up on printf vs echo can be found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: @MarounMaroun hahaha... you made me lol.